# Update a tkinter texvariable label during a function

Tags: python, function, tkinter, label

I am trying to make a program that controls a luminar testing machine.
I was programming the GUI with `tkinter`, and I have made a button that launches a function that does the tests on the machine.
The function launches 3 different test on the machine, and in the GUI there is a box (`ttk.Label(root, textvariable=x)`) that must be updated with the results of the three processes individually.

When I push the button the three tests start correctly, and when the function ends the text is correctly updated. But I want to update it during the function, to show the results of every test until the function ends.

I was looking and trying and I haven't been able to do the update of the text during the function, instead of when the function ends.

Could someone help me please?

Here's the code of the function I use:

```
def inittest():
    if fn.initground()=='Y':
        progtext = ('Ground test has started')
        progress.set(progtext)
    elif fn.initground()=='N'
        progtext = ('Ground test has failed')
        progress.set(progtext)
    response = fn.receivedata()
    if len(response) == 1:
        progtext = (progtext + 'Data not received')
        progress.set(progtext)
    else:
        progtext = (progtext + response)
        progress.set(progtext)
    time.sleep(2)

    if fn.initisolate()=='Y':
        progtext = ('Isolate test has started')
        progress.set(progtext)
    elif fn.initisolate()=='N'
        progtext = ('Isolate test has failed')
        progress.set(progtext)
    response = fn.receivedata()
    if len(response) == 1:
        progtext = (progtext + 'Data not received')
        progress.set(progtext)
    else:
        progtext = (progtext + response)
        progress.set(progtext)
    time.sleep(2)

    if fn.initfun()=='Y':
        progtext = ('Function test has started')
        progress.set(progtext)
    elif fn.initfun()=='N'
        progtext = ('Function test has failed')
        progress.set(progtext)
    response = fn.receivedata()
    if len(response) == 1:
        progtext = (progtext + 'Data not received')
        progress.set(progtext)
    else:
        progtext = (progtext + response)
        progress.set(progtext)
    time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: Assuming progress is your textvariable, I think you should be using tkinter's after command, not time.sleep(). My understanding is that sleep halts all processing including tkinter updating

Comment: Ok, I have tried using after, and it happens the same, even the function not ends the textvariable label doesn't update.

Comment: Print the variables to see what they contain, starting with response and len(response).  What happens when len(response)==0 or fn.initground() does not equal "Y" or "N"?

Comment: I have print the variables during all processes of the sequence, and it prints in the command line, but it doesn't update on the tinter GUI until the function ends.
fn.initground() (and initisolate() & initfun()) only returns "Y" or "N".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after a long time trying code, I finally got the code that works.
I set a global value before the function start and modify it after every test has done. After this, I recall the function and it starts the second test because of the global value I set has changed.
Here's the code I use.
Thanks for all the help.

```
global action
action = 1

def inittest():

    global action

    if action == 1:
         def testground():
         global progtext
         if fn.initground()=='Y':
             progtext = ('Ground test has started')
             progress.set(progtext)
         elif fn.initground()=='N'
             progtext = ('Ground test has failed')
             progress.set(progtext)
         response = fn.receivedata()
         if len(response) == 1:
             progtext = (progtext + 'Data not received')
             progress.set(progtext)
         else:
             progtext = (progtext + response)
             progress.set(progtext)
         time.sleep(2)
     action = 2
     testground()
     root.after(1000, inittest)

     if action == 2:

         def testisolate():
         global progtext
         if initisolate()=='Y':
             progtext = (progtext + 'Isolate test has started')
             progress.set(progtext)
         elif fn.initisolate()=='N'
             progtext = (progtext + 'Isolate test has failed')
             progress.set(progtext)
         response = fn.receivedata()
         if len(response) == 1:
             progtext = (progtext + 'Data not received')
             progress.set(progtext)
         else:
             progtext = (progtext + response)
             progress.set(progtext)
         time.sleep(2)
     action = 3
     testisolate()
     root.after(1000, inittest)

     if action == 3:

         def testfun():
         global progtext
         if initfun()=='Y':
             progtext = (progtext + 'Function test has started')
             progress.set(progtext)
         elif fn.initfun()=='N'
             progtext = (progtext + 'Function test has failed')
             progress.set(progtext)
         response = fn.receivedata()
         if len(response) == 1:
             progtext = (progtext + 'Data not received')
             progress.set(progtext)
         else:
             progtext = (progtext + response)
             progress.set(progtext)
         time.sleep(2)
     action = 1
     testfun()
```